# How do you refer to an error in Bash/Shell Script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is it possible to refer to an error?  Here is my code:

```
read dir
mkdir /Users/Dillon/$dir
```

And if the directory is already there, it tells me `mkdir: /Users/Dillon/(dir): File exists`

.  Is there a way to state that if it already exists to not not show error?

Comment: You can check for an error with a command by checking `$?` immediately after executing the command most (all?) *nix commands set `$?` to 0 if they execute successfully and some other value otherwise.  So, `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then ...` will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You can test for directory existence before running the command:

```
[ -d /Users/Dillon/$dir ] || mkdir /Users/Dillon/$dir
```

Alternately, you can use the `-p` flag:

```
mkdir -p /Users/Dillon/$dir
```

This will make the directory if it does not yet exist, as well as any missing directories in the path.  It does not complain if the directory already exists.  It will complain if any segment of the path exists, but isn't a directory or a symlink to a directory.

Answer (score 1):

To suppress error output for any command, redirect the stderr stream to /dev/null

```
mkdir /Users/Dillion/$dir 2> /dev/null
```

Or for this one specific case, you could first check for the existence of the directory and bypass the mkdir call if the directory exists:

```
if [ ! -d /Users/Dillion/$dir ]; then
   mkdir /Users/Dillion/$dir
fi
```